# Issues with Class.forName in Java code using Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, database-connection

I am using Eclipse IDE Version: Helios Service Release 2 and JDK version 1.6. I have SQL Server 2008 installed on my system. I have downloaded Microsoft JDBC driver and included the path of the jar file in Eclipse IDE-> Project Properties->Java build Path-> Libraries -> Add External jars.

I have written this piece of code for database connection:

```
package com.ucs.test;

import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectDatabase {

Connection DBconnection = null;
String dbName = "silkopenview";
String userName = "SilkTestAdmin"; 
String password = "Nbv12345";

Class.forName(drivername);

DBconnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbName,userName,password);


}
```

But I get the following errors:

*Syntax error on token "DBconnection", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

Syntax error on token "drivername", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)*

I am new to Java and Eclipse IDE. Please help me in correcting this errors. A quick help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Class.forName(drivername);
DBconnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbName,userName,password);
```

You can not put them where you placed in your class, You have to put them in constructor/method, like :

```
public class ConnectDatabase {

   Connection dbConnection = null;
   String dbName = "silkopenview";
   String userName = "SilkTestAdmin"; 
   String password = "Nbv12345";

   public Connection getConnection() {
      Class.forName(drivername);
      dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbName,userName,password);
      return dbConnection;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! I have added a method and then placed my code in simple try catch block and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

These statements:

```
Class.forName(drivername);    
DBconnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbName,userName,password);
```

are currently just part of the class - not in a method, or constructor, or static initializer etc. You probably want to put them in a constructor. The previous ones are okay, as they're variable declarations - although whether you really *want* them to be instance variables is a different matter.

Also note that `driverName` isn't declared anywhere in the code you've given.

On a tangential note, if you're sufficiently new to Java that you're running into this sort of thing, you should abandon your current code completely: you're currently trying to run before you can walk. Talking to databases correctly is non-trivial, and trying to learn how to do that *while also learning Java syntax* is going to be messy. Start with simple console apps that let you learn the language and some of the core types (strings, numbers, collections etc) and *then* move on to databases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your statements in a method rather than in the class block.

```
Class.forName(drivername);
```

and

```
DBconnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbName,userName,password);
```

Given that you're using SQL Server, you will need to declare your `driverName`:

```
final String driverName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
```

Comment: Hi All, I was able to proceed and there are no errors while building the code. But I get this error even though the credentials/connection url provided are correct. Error: *Login failed for user 'HPOM-QA-WIN\Administrator'.ClientConnectionId:bb3634f3-a35a-4dfb-9d5f-6fb6acb860a5 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)* Please help!!

Comment: Hi All! Please help in resolving this issue. Appreciate an immediate response.

Comment: I am still stuck with this issue. Please provide your suggestions.